# Xamarin Forms 3.1 UWP DisplayActionSheet - The parameter is incorrect. Placement target needs to be in the visual tree

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I upgraded my Xamarin Forms project to Forms 3.1

In UWP, I'm displaying Action Sheet inside of a static class like below:

```
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet();
```

Forms 2.5 displays the Action Sheet with no issue.

Forms 3.1 crashes.

```
ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

Placement target needs to be in the visual tree.
```

Did something change in the way `DisplayActionSheet` works inside a class file?

I don't have a reference to `ContentPage` at this point.

Is there a better way to `DisplayActionSheet` without a reference to `ContentPage`?

See here: https://github.com/aherrick/UWPDisplayActionSheet

Comment: If this is true, I think it's best to log an issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3144

Comment: If you change `App` to `Application` does it work?

Comment: Nope same result unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sorry for my the previous incorrect answer**

The problem is that the `Page1` is `ModalPage`, but you still use the page where in the `NavigationStack` as parent cause `ActionSheet` render in the wrong place.

```
public static Page Instance
{
    get
    {
        Page ret = null;
        if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack != null)
            ret = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

        if (ret == null)
            ret = Application.Current.MainPage;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

If you used `PushModalAsync` method the page will stack in `ModalStack`

```
get
{
    Page ret = null;
    if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack != null)
        ret = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault();

    if (ret == null)
        ret = Application.Current.MainPage;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Nico, is this correct? I thought the OnAppearing() method is being called in UWP stack of Xamarin forms based on the Page.Loaded event > https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/093a4efa2da9cb681890158ca8ee9bb6f30b0a8c/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsPresenter.cs#L23 would that not assume the ( reading the uwp docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded ) page being ready in the XAML tree?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I've updated my sample to prove it has nothing to do with OnAppearing() It's still erroring.

Comment: @aherrick I have updated my answer and corrected my mistake.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT looks like that got it thanks! However I still feel like it's a regression with Forms